# Can a regular icosahedron contain a rational point on each face?

Tags: nt.number-theory, discrete-geometry, geometry-of-numbers

The title says it all: Is there a (regular) icosahedron containing a rational point on each of its faces?

For other Platonic solids, the affirmative answer is easy. Indeed, regular tetrahedra, cubes, and octahedra may have all their vertices rational. A dodecahedron cannot, but 8 of its vertices form a cube, and each face contains an edge of that cube as its diagonal.

Comment: Two different (mis)spellings of *icosahedron* in one question!  Nice question anyway.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: Can all of the vertices of an icosahedron be rational?

Comment: @KentaSuzuki No, you cannot find a regular pentagon in the integer lattice (in any dimension).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509194/regular-icosahedron-with-integer-vertices

Comment: I'm curious: is there a pentagon with a rational point on each edge?

Comment: Here's an example that doesn't work but comes close. The icosahedron with vertices $(\pm (\phi-2), \pm (\phi-1), 0)$, $(\pm (\phi - 1), 0, \pm (\phi - 2))$, $(0, \pm (\phi-2), \pm (\phi-1))$ has the property that each point in the set $\{ (1,1,-1), (1,-1,1), (1,-1,-1), (-1,1,1), (-1,1,-1), (-1,-1,1) \}$ lies on six of the extended faces of the icosahedron (with each extended face having at least one). However, one can show that for 12 of the faces of this icosahedron, any rational point lies a distance at least $\sqrt{2}$ from the origin, while the circumradius is $\sqrt{7-4\phi} < \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Curious side question: is it possible that the answer depends on the dimension? (e.g., that such an icosahedron exists in $\mathbb{R}^4$ but not $\mathbb{R}^3$)

Comment: In all other Platonic solids, faces are three- or fourfold rotations of each other, which allows sets of corresponding points to fit into the integer lattice (by properly positioning and scaling the polyhedron). But with the icosahedron the rotation is fivefold, which precludes fitting one set of corresponding points to the integer lattice on all faces.