# Is there a regular pentagon with a rational point on each edge?

Tags: nt.number-theory, discrete-geometry, geometry-of-numbers

This question was asked by Yaakov Baruch in the comments to the question [Can a regular icosahedron contain a rational point on each face?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/452847/5712) It seems that this question deserves special attention.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Sorry, wrong idea. I delete my answer.

Comment: I tried to use Groebner bases to handle this question, but things get quite massive. Not sure if there is a trivial reason for that, but the only thing which came out so far is that if there is a rational point on each edge, then the slopes of the edges are contained in $\mathbb Q(\sin2\pi/5)$, but none of the slopes is rational.

Comment: @PeterMueller I think it would be worth expanding your comment into an answer, even though it is only a partial answer.

Comment: How about an equilateral triangle (in the plane) with a rational point on each edge (maybe required to be distinct)? Is this trivial? (I don't see it either way.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen That seems to me to be pretty trivial. You can start with any three points, say $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,0)$, and draw three lines through them in such a way that they are (i) all at 60 degree angles to each other, and (ii) each of the three points lies between the two points of intersection with the other two lines. For example I could take the line through $(0,0)$ to be $y=-x$, which would then fix the choice of the other two lines. (To do regular $n$-gons for $n>3$, you need to do more to make sure the sides of the $n$-gons are equal, but for triangles condition (i) suffices.)

Comment: (Come to think of it, it's probably not correct to say you can start from any triple of points. Obviously three collinear points won't work, and three points that are "close to collinear" will probably also pose problems. My implicit thinking was: start with three rational points that are sufficiently close to a triple of points already lying on the sides of an equilateral triangle, which you can do by virtue of the density of rational points in the Euclidean plane. For such triples you can be sure that the required inequalities are satisfied.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm considering a more generic problem, allowing points to lie on lines containing edges. Let use the $\mathbf p_i$ for the pentagon vertices and $\mathbf q_i$ for the rational points. The pentagon is fixed by its center $\mathbf c$ and $\mathbf r = \mathbf p_1 - \mathbf c$. Let $R$ be the rotation matrix by $\frac{2\pi}{5}$. Also let $T = R^{-1} = R^\top$.

The vertices of the pentagon are given by
$$
\mathbf p_i = \mathbf c + R^i \mathbf r, \quad i = 0,\dots,4.
$$
Index $i$ in $\mathbf p_i$ is considered modulo 5.

The points $\mathbf q_i$ can be represented as
$$
\mathbf q_i = (1 - \lambda_i)\mathbf p_i + \lambda_i \mathbf p_{i+1} = 
\mathbf c + R^i((1 - \lambda_i) I + \lambda_i R) \mathbf r, \quad \lambda_i \in \mathbb R.
$$
We do not restrict $\lambda_i \in [0, 1]$, so $\mathbf q_i$ can be anywhere on the line passing through $\mathbf p_i$ and $\mathbf p_{i+1}$.

Let's consider auxiliary points $\mathbf a_i$ defined as
$$
\mathbf a_i = T^i (\mathbf q_i - \mathbf c).
$$
This points satisfy $\mathbf a_i = (1 - \lambda_i) \mathbf r + \lambda_i R \mathbf r$ so they all lie in some line $\ell = \operatorname{aff}(\mathbf r, R \mathbf r)$.

Let's construct such linear combinations of $\mathbf a_i$ so they are free of $\mathbf c$. This basically reduces to finding trivial combinations $\sum_{k=0}^4 \alpha_k T^k = O$. It's easy to see that columns of the linear combination vanish at the same time, so the equality reduces to
$$
\sum_{k=0}^4 \alpha_k \cos \frac{2\pi k}{5} = 0\\
\sum_{k=0}^4 \alpha_k \sin \frac{2\pi k}{5} = 0
$$
There are three linearly independent solutions to the system, forming the following null space matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\phi \\
-1 & \phi\\
\phi & -1 & \phi\\
& \phi & -1\\
&& \phi
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$, the golden ratio. It is easy to verify that
$$\phi T^{i+1} - T^i + \phi T^{i-1} = T^i (\phi (R + T) - I) = O.$$

The combinations that are free from $\mathbf c$ are:
$$
\mathbf b_i = \phi \mathbf a_{i-1} - \mathbf a_i + \phi \mathbf a_{i+1} = 
\phi T^{i-1}\mathbf q_{i-1} - T^i\mathbf q_i + \phi T^{i+1}\mathbf q_{i+1}, \quad i = 1, 2, 3.
$$
Points $\mathbf b_i$ also lie on a same line $\ell' = (2\phi - 1) \ell$. Therefore
$$
(\mathbf b_3 - \mathbf b_2) \vee (\mathbf b_2 - \mathbf b_1) = 0.
$$
Here $\vee$ is the pseudoscalar (or skew) product.

By using the trigonometric form $T^k = \cos \frac{2\pi k}{5} I + \sin \frac{2\pi k}{5} J$ and performing some lengthy computation, one can obtain
$$
\frac {4}{\phi^2} (\mathbf b_3 - \mathbf b_2) \vee (\mathbf b_2 - \mathbf b_1) = \\ =
\left(\sum_{i=0}^4 \mathbf q_i \vee \mathbf q_{i-1}\right) (\sqrt{5} - 1) +
\left(\sum_{i=0}^4 \mathbf q_i \vee \mathbf q_{i-2}\right) (\sqrt{5} + 3) + \\ +
\left(\sum_{i=0}^4 \mathbf q_i \cdot (\mathbf q_{i-1}-\mathbf q_{i-2})\right) \sqrt{10 + 2\sqrt{5}}.
$$
The indices are considered modulo 5.

Now let
$$
A = \sum_{i=0}^4 \mathbf q_i \vee \mathbf q_{i-1},\\
B = \sum_{i=0}^4 \mathbf q_i \vee \mathbf q_{i-2},\\
C = \sum_{i=0}^4 \mathbf q_i \cdot (\mathbf q_{i-1}-\mathbf q_{i-2}),\\
D = A + B,\\
E = 3B - A.
$$
Note that $A, B, C, D, E \in \mathbb Q$.

We finally have a necessary condition
$$
D \sqrt{5} + E + C \sqrt{10 + 2\sqrt{5}} = 0.
$$
It is easy to show that there is no nontrivial solution:
$$
5D^2 + E^2 + 2\sqrt{5}DE = C^2 (10 + 2\sqrt{5})\\
5D^2 + E^2 - 10C^2 = 2(C^2 - DE)\sqrt{5}\\
C^2 - DE = 0\\
5D^2 + E^2 = 10C^2 = 10DE\\
(E - 5D)^2 = 20D^2 \\
E = (5 \pm 2\sqrt{5})D\\
C = D = E = 0.
$$
So the only possibility is $A = B = 0$. But $A$ is twice the [oriented area of the polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) formed by $\mathbf q_{0},\dots,\mathbf q_{4}$. Similarly, $B$ is twice the area of the star-shaped polygon with permuted vertices $\mathbf q_0, \mathbf q_2, \mathbf q_4, \mathbf q_1, \mathbf q_3$.

This surely can't happen when $\mathbf q_{i}$ lie on the sides, since then polygon $\mathbf q_0, \mathbf q_1, \mathbf q_2, \mathbf q_3, \mathbf q_4$ is convex and nonempty.

**Update**. However there are rational solutions to $A = B = C = 0$, for example
$$
\mathbf q_0 = \left(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{2}\right),
\mathbf q_1 = (1,2),
\mathbf q_2 = \left(1,\frac{1}{2}\right),
\mathbf q_3 = \left(2,\frac{1}{2}\right),
\mathbf q_4 = \left(2,\frac{7}{6}\right).
$$
This particular one was obtained by trial and error method by plugging 1 and 2 for unknowns and solving the remaining system.

Knowing $\mathbf q_i$ we can compute $\mathbf b_i$, obtaining the $\ell'$ line. Divinding it by $2\phi-1$ we get the $\ell$ line where $\mathbf a_i, \mathbf r$ and $R\mathbf r$ are located. The $\mathbf r$ can be found from the following linear system
$$
((2\phi-1) \mathbf r - \mathbf b_1) \vee (\mathbf b_2 - \mathbf b_1) = 0\\
((2\phi-1) R\mathbf r - \mathbf b_1) \vee (\mathbf b_2 - \mathbf b_1) = 0
$$
Similarly $\mathbf c$ can be obtained as the solution to
$$
((2\phi-1) (\mathbf q_0 - \mathbf c) - \mathbf b_1) \vee (\mathbf b_2 - \mathbf b_1) = 0\\
((2\phi-1) T (\mathbf q_0 - \mathbf c) - \mathbf b_1) \vee (\mathbf b_2 - \mathbf b_1) = 0
$$

The layout of the points and the pentagon is shown in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Impressive. (And I'm glad I gave up my own attempt to a solution early on.)

Answer (score 16):

**Update 3:** The answer by uranix which finally settles the question is extremely clever! The essential point is the algebraic relation between $C, D, E$. The following Sage code (which can be run e.g. in the [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)) verifies that his calculation is indeed correct:

```
vars = [f'l_{i}' for i in range(5)]
vars += ['cx', 'cy', 'rx', 'ry', 's']
S = PolynomialRing(QQ, vars)
S.inject_variables()
f = s^4 - 5/4*s^2 + 5/16 # s = sin(2*pi/5), f = minpol of s
c = 2*s^2 - 3/2          # c = cos(2*pi/5)

R = matrix([[c, s], [-s, c]])

def redvec(v):
    return vector((v[0]%f, v[1]%f))

def p(i):
    return redvec(vector(S, (cx, cy)) + R^(i%5)*vector(S, (rx, ry)))

def l(i):
    return S.gen(i%5)

def q(i):
    return (1-l(i))*p(i) + l(i)*p(i+1)

def pseu(u, v):
    return matrix([u,v]).det()

def scalp(u, v):
    return u[0]*v[0] + u[1]*v[1]

A = sum(pseu(q(i), q(i-1)) for i in range(5))
B = sum(pseu(q(i), q(i-2)) for i in range(5))
C = sum(scalp(q(i), q(i-1)-q(i-2)) for i in range(5))
D = A + B
E = 3*B - A

uranix = ((5*D^2 + E^2 -10*C^2)^2 - 20*(C^2 - D*E)^2) % f
print(uranix == 0)
```

**Update 2:** (Answering the question of uranix in the comments) In `L`, we set $m=m_0+m_1s+m_2s^2+m_3s^3$, and grouping by powers of $s$, we get $16$ equations in $y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4$ and the $m_i$'s. After running the displayed code from the original answer, run the following code:

```
vars += ['m0', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3']
S = PolynomialRing(QQ, vars)
S.inject_variables()
LL = [S(z).subs({m:m0 + m1*s + m2*s^2 + m3*s^3})%f for z in L]
N = []
for z in LL:
    N += [S(_) for _ in z.polynomial(s).coefficients()]
I = ideal(N)
cubic = 64*m0*m1^2 - 64*m0^2*m2 - 80*m0*m2^2 - 20*m2^3 + 160*m0*m1*m3 + 40*m1*m2*m3 + 80*m0*m3^2 + 25*m2*m3^2 - 64*m2
print(cubic in I)
print(I.elimination_ideal(S.gens()[:7]))
```

The second to last line verifies that the cubic indeed has to vanish. And the last line shows how the cubic was obtained from eliminating variables. (If one would like to know how `cubic` is expressed in term of the polynomials in `N`, run `cubic.lift(I)`.)

**Update 1:** With the notation from below, an example where an edge has slope $m$ requires $m\in\mathbb Q(s)$ where $s=\sin(2\pi/5)$. Note that $s$ has degree $4$ over $\mathbb Q$. If we write $m=m_0+m_1s+m_2s^2+m_3s^3$ with rational $m_i$, then a further necessary condition is
\begin{equation}
64m_0m_1^2 - 64m_0^2m_2 - 80m_0m_2^2 - 20m_2^3 + 160m_0m_1m_3 + 40m_1m_2m_3 + 80m_0m_3^2 + 25m_2m_3^2 - 64m_2=0.
\end{equation}
This condition is essentially sufficient for the following: There are $5$ distinct rational points $u_i$, one on each *line* through an edge. This cubic has many rational solutions. (I guess it is rationally parametrized or at least unirational) Still, none of these points so far forced all the $u_i$'s to lie *inside* each edge. This additional condition amounts to high degree polynomial inequalities.

---

This is an attempt giving some partial results.

Set $s=\sin(2\pi/5)$ and $c=2s^2 - 3/2=\cos(2\pi/5)$. We show that if there is a positive answer, then the slopes of the edges are contained in the field $\mathbb Q(s)$, but none of the slopes is rational.

Let $u_0,\ldots,u_4$ be five putative rational points on the five sides of the regular pentagon. We allow that some points coincide. Note however that $u_i=u_j$ can only happen if $i-j\in\{-1,0,1\}$ (indices taken modulo $5$).

The rational group $\text{SO}(2,\mathbb Q)$ of rotations is dense in $\text{SO}(2,\mathbb R)$ (in view of the rational parametrization $x=2t/(1+t^2), y=(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$ of the unit circle).

In particular, we may and do assume the following:

- None of the slopes is vertical.
- If $(x_i,y_i)=u_i\ne u_j=(x_j,y_j)$, then $x_i\ne x_j$ and $y_i\ne y_j$.
- $x_0=y_0=0$, $x_1=1$.

Let $m$ be the slope of the edge through $u_0$. By repeated rotation of the vector $(1,m)$ by $2\pi/5$, we get the slopes through the $u_i$'s. By intersecting the lines through these points, we get the vertices of the pentagon. Let $p_i$ be the intersection of the lines through $u_i$ and $u_{i+1}$. The condition which has to hold is that the vector $p_{i+2}-p_{i+1}$ is $p_{i+1}-p_i$ rotated by $2\pi/5$.

For $i=3$ this yields the condition
\begin{align}
q_0+q_1m &= 0\text{ where}\\
q_0 &= (-4x_3 + 4x_4)s^3 + (2y_1 + 2y_3)s^2 + (3x_3 - 2x_4 - 1)s - 3/2y_1 - y_3 + 1/2y_4\\
q_1 &= (-4y_3 + 4y_4)s^3 + (-2x_3 - 2)s^2 + (-y_1 + 3y_3 - 2y_4)s + x_3 - 1/2x_4 + 3/2
\end{align}
We use that $s$ has degree $4$ over $\mathbb Q$, and $s^4 - 5/4s^2 + 5/16=0$.

Suppose that $m$ is not in the field generated by $s$. Then $q_1=q_0=0$. The linear independence of $1,s,s^2,s^3$ yields $8$ equations in the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s. Let $q_i[j]$ be the coefficient in $q_i$ of $s^j$.
We get the contradiction
\begin{equation}
0 = q_0[3] + 8q_1[0] + 2q_1[2] = (-4x_3 + 4x_4)+8(x_3 - 1/2x_4 + 3/2)+2(-2x_3 - 2)=8.
\end{equation}
Similarly, we show that $m$ is not rational. Suppose that $m$ is rational. Then $q[j]:=q_0[j]+mq_1[j]$ vanishes for $j=0,1,2,3$. One computes that
\begin{equation}
8mq[0]-4q[1]+4mq[2]-3q[3]=4(1-x_4)(1+m^2),
\end{equation}
so $4(1-x_4)(1+m^2)=0$. Of course $1+m^2\ne0$, hence $x_4=1=x_1$, which contradicts our assumption $u_4\ne u_1$ (and different $x$-coordinates for different $u_i$'s).

The SageMath code below does the actual computation. In order to continue, one can use $q$ to eliminate $m$ in the other equations (collected in the list `L` in the program). Using Groebner bases one gets certain conditions on the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s, but I wasn't able to get a contradiction, nor a positive example. The computations just became too heavy, so a better idea is needed.

```
vars = [f'x_{i}' for i in range(2, 5)]
vars += [f'y_{i}' for i in range(1, 5)]
vars += ['m', 's']
R = PolynomialRing(QQ, vars)
R.inject_variables()
f = s^4 - 5/4*s^2 + 5/16
c = 2*s^2 - 3/2

def u(i):
    i = i%5
    if i == 0:
        return 0, 0
    if i == 1:
        return 1, y_1
    return R.gen(i-2), R.gen(i+2)

def rot(u):
    """Rotate vector u by 2*pi/5"""
    x, y = u
    return (x*c - y*s)%f, (x*s + y*c)%f

def diff(u, v):
    return u[0]-v[0], u[1]-v[1]

slope = (1, m)
p = []
for k in range(7):
    ux, uy = u(k)
    sux, suy = slope
    slope = rot(slope)
    vx, vy = u(k+1)
    svx, svy = slope
    x = suy*svx*ux - sux*svx*uy - sux*svy*vx + sux*svx*vy
    y = suy*svy*ux - sux*svy*uy - suy*svy*vx + suy*svx*vy
    p.append((x%f, y%f))

deltas = [diff(p[k+1], p[k]) for k in range(6)]

L = [diff(deltas[k+1], rot(deltas[k]))[0] for k in range(4)]
q = [z for z in L if z.degree(m) == 1][0]
lq = [R(z) for z in q.polynomial(m)]

def L2N(L): #Get the coefficients of the polynomial in s
    N = []
    for z in L:
        N += [R(_) for _ in z.polynomial(s).coefficients()]
    return N

print('Checking that m in Q(s):')
N = L2N(lq)
print(1 in ideal(N), R(1).lift(N))

print('Checking that m is not rational:')
N = L2N([q])
w = (1-x_4)*(m^2+1)
print(w in ideal(N), w.lift(N))
```

Comment: Your necessary condition looks like a cubic form, but the last summand is linear. Is it correct?

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov Yes it is, there is no copy/pase error. Btw, my colleague Stephan Elsenhans now computed a (massive!) unirational parametrization of this cubic.

Comment: Could you please explain how the cubic was obtained? 

As far as I understood, L = 0 gives 4 x 4 = 16 equations (each i and each power of s) for 7 + 4 = 11 unknowns (y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 and m0, m1, m2, m3).

Comment: @uranix I added how the cubic was obtained.

Answer (score 15):

It is possible to modify [Uranix's lovely answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/462054/177778) to show that the only $n \ge 3$ for which there is a regular $n$-gon with a rational point on each side are $n=3,4,8$ (for which simple constructions have already been demonstrated here).

Observing that one can obtain a regular $n$-gon by extending $n$ sides of a regular $nm$-gon, it suffices to prove impossibility in the case in which $n$ is $16,6,9$, or an odd prime $p > 3$.
Fix such an $n$ and suppose for sake of contradiction such an $n$-gon exists. Let $q_i$ be a rational point on the $i$th side (oriented counterclockwise), $p$ the center of the polygon, and $T$ rotation by $-\frac{2 \pi}{n}$. It will also be convenient to define $c(k) = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)$ and $s(k) = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)$.

Now exactly as in Uranix's answer the points $$
T^i(q_i-p)
$$
lie in a common line. Thus for each $k$, the sum $$
a_k = \sum_{i=1}^n (T^i(q_i-p)) \vee (T^{i+k}(q_{i+k}-p))
$$
is equal to $0$ (where indices are taken modulo $n$). Now using $x \vee T^ky = c(k) x \vee y - s(k) x \cdot y$ we have \begin{align*} 
a_k &= \sum_{i=1}^n (q_i-p) \vee (T^{k}(q_{i+k}-p))\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n [c(k) (q_{i}-p) \vee (q_{i+k}-p) - s(k) (q_{i}-p) \cdot (q_{i+k}-p)]\\
&= c(k)\sum_{i=1}^n  q_{i} \vee q_{i+k} - s(k) \sum_{i=1}^n  q_{i}\cdot q_{i+k}+2s(k)\sum_{i=1}^n p\cdot (q_i - p ).\\
\end{align*}
We wish to be rid of those terms depending on $p$.
Denote $V_k = \sum_{i=1}^n q_{i} \vee q_{i+k}$ and $D_k = \sum_{i=1}^n q_{i} \cdot q_{i+k}$, and observe that \begin{align*}
0 &= 2s(m)a_k - 2s(k)a_m \\&= 2s(m)c(k)V_k - 2s(k)c(m)V_m-2s(m)s(k)(D_m-D_k)
\\&= s(m+k)(V_k-V_m)+s(m-k)(V_k+V_m)-(c(m-k)-c(m+k))(D_m-D_k)
\end{align*} This is finally our necessary condition for solutions to exist. Most of the argument works with $m=2,k=1$ where we have \begin{equation} \label{eqn:main}
s(3)(V_1-V_2)+s(1)(V_1+V_2)-(c(1)-c(3))(D_2-D_1)=0\tag{$*$}
\end{equation} Note the crucial facts that $D_k,V_k$ are rational and that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are the volumes of the polytopes $q_1q_2q_3...$ and $q_1q_3q_5...$ and thus positive when $n > 4$.

We now derive a contradiction for every listed $n$.

Firstly if $n$ is an odd prime and greater than $3$, we have that $\{s(1),s(3),c(1),c(3)\}$ are $\mathbb Q$-linearly independent since $\{e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{n}},e^{\pm 3\frac{2\pi i}{n}}\}$ are $\mathbb Q(i)$-linearly independent. Thus for \eqref{eqn:main} to hold we require $$(V_1-V_2)=(V_1+V_2)=(D_2-D_1)=0$$ so in particular $V_1=V_2=0$, contradicting positivity of the $V_k$.

If $n=6$, then $s(3)$ vanishes and \eqref{eqn:main} becomes $$
0=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(V_1+V_2)-\frac{3}{2}(D_2-D_1),
$$
so again $V_1+V_2=0$, contradicting the positivity of the $V_k$.

If $n=9$ we use the alternate condition $$s(5)(V_2-V_3)+s(1)(V_2+V_3)-(c(1)-c(5))(D_3-D_2)=0$$ for which the same argument as in the odd prime case applies to show $s(1), s(5), c(1)-c(5)$ are linearly independent, giving $(V_2-V_3)=(V_2+V_3)=(D_3-D_2)=0$ and thus $V_2=0$, again a contradiction.

Finally if $n=16$, then $c(1)$ and $c(3)$ are $\mathbb Q$-linearly independent, but $s(1) = c(3)$ and $s(3)=c(1)$, so \eqref{eqn:main} becomes $$
V_1-V_2 = D_2-D_1 = -V_1-V_2
$$
and thus $2V_1=0$ in this case, contradicting the positivity of the $V_k$.

This answer of course relies heavily on the stipulation that the rational points lie on each side. If this is removed there are solutions for at least the pentagon (as shown by Uranix) and the hexagon as well. I am curious if any other $n$ admit such solutions.

Comment: Nice work, your proof removes many unnecessary overcomplications of mine.

Comment: As to "I am curious if any other $n$ admit such solutions" : Some slight modification of the programs in my answer show that there are no solutions for $n=7, 9$ and $11$. For $n=13$, however, the answer depends on whether a complicated $2$-dimensional variety (in $12$ variables) has a rational point.

Comment: If $d$ is the degree of $\sin(2\pi/n)$ over $\mathbb Q$, then there is a solution with a rational point on each line through two consecutive points of the regular $n$-gon if and only if a certain variety in $d$ variables has a rational point. For $n=5$ the variety is the cubic from my answer. For $n=7$ and $9$, the variety doesn't even have complex points. However, for $n=13$, there are complex points, but no rational ones.

Comment: Fascinating! For $n=16$ we should have $d=4$ (I suppose in general $d = \varphi(4n/(16,n-4))/2$), and this case was harder than the others for me. What is the situation there?

Comment: @MatthewBolan For $n=16$ the variety actually has rational points, which nevertheless don't give solutions for the question. (So the necessary condition of existence of rational points is not quite sufficient.)